# How to determine where an npm package was installed from?

Tags: npm, npm-package

How can we determine where an npm package was installed from?

I know we can use [`npm view <package>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view) to view information about a package from a registry, but what about packages that were not installed from a registry (e.g. a git repo or local directory)?

Specifically, I'm trying to programatically determine whether a globally-installed npm package (CLI tool) was installed from a git repo or from a local directory. This package isn't published in any registries.

**Update:** For example, one could install a global package from GitHub by either of the following methods:

- `npm install -g git+https://github.com/linclark/github-pages-deploy.git`
- `git clone https://github.com/linclark/github-pages-deploy && npm install -g github-pages-deploy`

How can you tell which method was used to install it?

Comment: Did you open the `package.json` file in the installed package? It has some more meta-data that gets added upon install.

Comment: @Evert can you share a specific field I should be looking for? I don't see anything different in the `package.json` under the global `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the package from it's name. It's look something like this in `package.json`

```
{

  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11", --> Global package ,
    "@githubUserName/test-package@1.0.0" --> private package
  }
}
```

Also if you are using any private packages then you must have to contain `.npmrc` which contain information about private package. You can check from there also.

Comment: The name in `package.json` isn't enough to tell where the package is from, even when considering any alternative registries that may have been configured. I can install an npm package from a local directory like `npm install -g .`, and the name could be anything I want, even something that exists in the official npm registry.